# "не обязательно" versus "необязательно"

Tags: грамматика, не-plus-adverb

In what cases should I say "не обязательно" and in what case should I say "необязательно"?

Is it correct here?:

> "Не стоит подменять понятие "защищать отечество" понятием "защищать
>   интересы отечества". Второе вовсе **не обязательно** оправдывает потери
>   жизней"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

Rosenthal et al., 66.6:

> Примечание 1. Раздельное написание *не* с прилагательным, имеющим при себе пояснительные слова, встречается:
>
> …
>
> 2. при наличии в качестве пояснительных слов отрицательных местоимений и наречий (начинающихся с *ни*) или сочетаний *далеко не, вовсе не, отнюдь не*, например: *никому не известный адрес, ни в чем не повинные люди, нисколько не понятное выражение, ничуть не вредный напиток, далеко не простое решение, вовсе не бесплодные поиски, отнюдь не новый сюжет*; ср.: *неведомыми мне путями – никому не ведомыми путями*

This rule applies to ad-adjectival adverbs and proper adjectives alike (see 71.4):

> Пишутся раздельно с *не* наречия на *-о*, если при них в качестве пояснительного слова стоит отрицательное наречие, начинающееся с *ни*, либо сочетание *далеко не, вовсе не, отнюдь не* (ср. §66, п. 6, примеч. 1, подпункт 2), например: *докладчик говорил нисколько не убедительно, рукопись отредактирована отнюдь не плохо*

Comment: Обязательно - это наречие.

Comment: @AlexVB: you're right, but the part about adverbs just references this part and same rules apply. I'll add it.